# Windows 8 infrared mouse/keyboard not recognised

Tags: windows-8, lock-screen, infrared

My Windows 8 login screen requires a click of the mouse to open, then I need to enter a password.
But my infrared mouse/keyboard is not being recognised.

Can I bypass the Windows 8 lock screen so that I can get into Windows and check the status of my mouse/keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to enter a password, then it would be a major security flaw if there was a way to just bypass it, wouldn't it? You'll need to connect a USB keyboard+mouse to log on, then you can check your infrared keyboard+mouse status.